# How can i get an object like OLAPDataSetInterface in SAS 9.4

Tags: java, sas

I need get an object like OLAPDataSetInterface but without using an OLAP server.

I used to use:

```
//Connect to OLAP server
OLAPDataSetInterface cube = objectInSession.getOlapDataSet();
//Get the info
cube.execute("query_mdx");
```

I tried use DataSetInterface but doesnt work:

```
com.sas.sasserver.dataset.DataSetInterface ds = null;
//Getting my temporary table
ds.setDataSet("WORK.my_table");
```

And i do the following:

```
//BBDD connector

WorkspaceConnector connector = factory.getWorkspaceConnector(0L);
IWorkspace workspace = connector.getWorkspace();
ILanguageService ls = workspace.LanguageService();

//This creates my temporary table in the library WORK (WORK.my_table)
String stmt = "%include \"/saswork/MY_PROGRAM.sas\" ;";
ls.Submit(stmt);

com.sas.sasserver.dataset.DataSetInterface ds = null;
//ds = ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is in C# but hould help understand the dataset retrieval process. I don't work with SAS OLAP so cannot tellyou how to work that item.

```
    public string GetDataSet(string sasDirectory, string dataset)
    {
        Common.Log($"Getting SAS dataset ({dataset}) at {sasDirectory}");
        DataTable dt = new DataTable(dataset);
        try
        {
            using (var cn = new OleDbConnection($@"Provider=SAS.LocalProvider; Data Source={sasDirectory}"))
            {
                cn.Open();
                var cmd = cn.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.TableDirect;
                cmd.CommandText = dataset;
                var sas = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
                var ds = new System.Data.DataSet();
                sas.Fill(ds, dataset);
                dt = ds.Tables[0];
                Common.Log($"SAS dataset loaded.");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string errMessage = "Unable to get the SAS dataset. Library: " + sasDirectory + ", DataSet: " + dataset + ", " +
                ex.TargetSite.Name;
            Common.Log($"SAS Error in {MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name}", MessageType.Error, ex);
        }
        return dt.ToCsv('\t');
    }
```